# Multiple Sets in PowerApps OnSelect doesn't work

Tags: json, guid, powerapps, power-automate, onselect

I want to generate an ID using GUID in PowerApps and send this to the flow in PowerAutomate.
The first sample code works fine, which means, that everything is Ok.
The Second sample code is not triggered the flow at all and there is no error. Can anyone please tell me why.

First code:

```
Set( 
DATAJSON_NEW_PROJECT;
"{" & Char(34) & "flowdata" & Char(34) & ":
    {
    " & Char(34) & "uuid" & Char(34) & ":" & JSON(12345) & ", 
    " & Char(34) & "name" & Char(34) & ":" & JSON(TextInput_Projectname.Text) & "
}
}");;

DT_Reporting_Flow_0.Run(DATAJSON_NEW_PROJECT; "NewProjekt")
```

Second code:

```
Set( NewGUID; GUID() );;

Set( 
DATAJSON_NEW_PROJECT;
"{" & Char(34) & "flowdata" & Char(34) & ":
    {
    " & Char(34) & "uuid" & Char(34) & ":" & JSON(NewGUID) & ", 
    " & Char(34) & "name" & Char(34) & ":" & JSON(TextInput_Projectname.Text) & "
    }
}");;

DT_Reporting_Flow_0.Run(DATAJSON_NEW_PROJECT; "NewProjekt")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in powerapps and its working for your reference Here i am also copy the running code:

```
Set( NewGUID, GUID() );

Set( 
DATAJSON_NEW_PROJECT,
"{" & Char(34) & "flowdata" & Char(34) & ":
    {
    " & Char(34) & "uuid" & Char(34) & ":" & JSON(NewGUID) & ", 
    " & Char(34) & "name" & Char(34) & ":" & JSON(TextInput_Projectname.Text) & "
    }
}");

DT_Reporting_Flow_0.Run(DATAJSON_NEW_PROJECT, "NewProjekt")
```